# how to dispaly relational models in one table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, orm

I have three relational models that I want to display in a view in one table. following, I will list 3 models then the controller and the view.
and an error that come out from the controller.

**Model Documents**

```
public class Documents
{
    [Key]
    public int DocId { get; set; }

    public string DocName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmpId_From { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmpId_To { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public int OrganId_From { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public int OrganId_To { get; set; } 

    public Employee _Employee { get; set; }
    public Organization _Organization { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

**Organization**

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   List<Documents> x = _context.Documents.Include(e => e.Employee).Include(o => o.Organization).ToList();
   return View(x);
}
```

**The View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Documents>

@foreach (var item in Model.DocumentsList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.DocId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.DocName
        </td>
        <td>  // I can see item.Employee.EmpName but how to display it for this FK EmpId_From & EmpId_To
            @item.EmpId_From // item.Employee.EmpName for EmpId_From
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.EmpId_To // item.Employee.EmpName for EmpId_To
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.OrganId_From // item.Organization.OrgName for OrganId_From
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.OrganId_To // item.Organization.OrgName for OrganId_To
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**I get this error from the controller**

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name '_EmployeeEmp_ID'.
Invalid column name 'OrganizationOrgID'.
Invalid column name 'EmployeeEmp_ID'.
Invalid column name 'OrganizationOrgID'.'
```

Comment: any update? Does my reply answer your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if want to add relationship between the Documents and Employee, Organization, you could directly add the employee and Organization as the property inside the Documents. Then you could directly get the related employee and Organization's value.

Your model class will like this:

```
public class Documents
{
    [Key]
    public int DocId { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public Employee Emp_From { get; set; }

    public Employee Emp_To { get; set; }

    public Organization Organ_From { get; set; }
    public Organization Organ_To { get; set; }


}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgID { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
}
```

Home controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Documents> x = _dbContext.Documents.Include(e => e.Emp_From).Include(o => o.Emp_To).Include(o => o.Organ_From).Include(o => o.Organ_To).ToList();
         return View(x);
    }
```

View:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.DocId
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DocName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Emp_From.EmpName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Emp_To.EmpName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Organ_From.OrgName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Organ_To.OrgName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Result:

[image]